# Template string in a JS function call

Tags: javascript, string, object, template-strings

I have this object:

```
let user = {
    name: undefined,
    age: undefined,
    city: undefined,
}
```

and these arrays

```
props = ["name", "age", "city"];
values = ["alan", 90, "london"];
```

and i want to do something like this

```
for (i=0; i<props.length; i++){
    user.${prop[i]} = values[i];
}
```

But I can't figure out how to use template strings as I pretend

The idea is to generate a function that can fill given properties of an object with given values, avoiding writing a lot of function calls

Comment: format like `user[ props[i] ] = values[i];` should be what you need.

Comment: There's no reason to use a template string for it, see the linked question's answers. Just `user[prop[i]] = values[i];` does what you want. **If** the property name were being created from multiple things, you might use a template string, for instance ```user[`${prop[i]}_foo`] = value[i];```, but not for what you're doing above.